# How can I correctly select a MySql function value on a table having a specific alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-function, mysql-function

I am not so into database and I have the following problem extracting geographical coordinates from a **point** object in a query. I am using **MySql**.

So I have a table like this:

```
Field                 Type           Null     Key     Default    Extra                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id                    bigint(20)     NO       PRI                auto_increment                
localization_id       bigint(20)     NO       MUL                                          
market_name           varchar(255)   NO                                                
market_cod            varchar(255)   YES                                               
description           text           YES                                               
gps                   point          YES
```

As you can see the query contains the **gps** field having type **point**.

Running this query it works fine:

```
SELECT
    MD.market_name as market_name,
    MD.description as market_description,
    X(gps)as longitude,   
    Y(gps)as latitude
FROM MarketDetails as MD
```

And I am correctly retrieving the **longitude** and **latitude** field returned respectively by the **X(gps)** and **Y(gps)** functions.

The problem is that the **MarketDetails** table have the **MD** alias (because then I will put in JOIN with other tables), so I tried to alias also the previous **X(gps)** and **Y(gps)** functions, in this way:

```
SELECT
    MD.market_name as market_name,
    MD.description as market_description,
    MD.X(gps)as longitude,   
    MD.Y(gps)as latitude
FROM MarketDetails as MD
```

But executing this query I am obtaining the following error message:

```
#42000FUNCTION MD.X does not exist
```

So, what is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly referring to the X(gps) and Y(gps) of the table that have the **MD** alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias goes on the *columns*, not the *function*:

```
SELECT MD.market_name as market_name,
       MD.description as market_description,
       X(MD.gps)as longitude,   
       Y(MD.gps)as latitude
FROM MarketDetails MD;
```